# Marketo REST API - Smart Campaign

Tags: php, json, rest, marketo

I can create a new Marketo lead using an html form and the attached script (PHP + Rest API). It mostly works, the leads show up in Marketo.

The problem is, my Marketo setup requires new leads to be added to a particular "Smart Campaign".

On Marketo's Rest API [documentation](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#/), I found an endpoint for adding leads to a List, but not for adding to a Campaign. Have you run into this problem?

```
class UpsertLeads{
    //these are the CIN Marketo credentials
    public $host = "####";//CHANGE ME
    public $clientId = "####";//CHANGE ME
    public $clientSecret = "####";//CHANGE ME
    public $input; //an array of lead records as objects
    public $lookupField; //field used for deduplication
    public $action; //operation type, createOnly, updateOnly, createOrUpdate, createDuplicate

    public function postData(){
        $url = $this->host . "/rest/v1/leads.json?access_token=" . $this->getToken();
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $requestBody = $this->bodyBuilder();
        //commenting out
        //dont need to output this stuff in production
        //print_r($requestBody);
        curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
        curl_getinfo($ch);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        return $response;
    }

    private function getToken(){
        $ch = curl_init($this->host . "/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" . $this->clientId . "&client_secret=" . $this->clientSecret);
        curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('accept: application/json',));
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
        $token = $response->access_token;
        return $token;
    }

    private function bodyBuilder(){
        $body = new stdClass();
        if (isset($this->action)){
            $body->action = $this->action;
        }
        if (isset($this->lookupField)){
            $body->lookupField = $this->lookupField;
        }
        $body->input = $this->input;
        $json = json_encode($body);
        return $json;
    }

    private static function csvString($fields){
        $csvString = "";
        $i = 0;
        foreach($fields as $field){
            if ($i > 0){
                $csvString = $csvString . "," . $field;
            }elseif ($i === 0){
                $csvString = $field;
            }
        }
        return $csvString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to put your new Leads directly to a *Smart Campaign* via the API.
However, –as you noted– you can push them to a *List*, which is halfway to success. From there, the only thing you need to do is to configure the *Smart Campaign* in question to pick up the Leads from the *List* you populate.

You can do that on the *Smart List* tab of the *Smart Campaign* by setting up the `Added to List` trigger and point it to your *List*. Screenshot attached.

This way the new Lead will be immediately added to the *Smart List* as well.

[image: 'Added to List' trigger of Smart Campaign]